# Azure VM complete replication

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a azure vm setup that contains custom software, files, folders blah blah. At any point I will need to create multiple identical instances of the existing vm (maybe up to 30). I used the sysprep in the vm, in the azure portal I used the capture image for the vm and tried to create a new VM from the image. The new vm created from the image did not contain any of the files from the previous vm.

What would be the best approach in preserving a complete image of the vm and be able to mass deploy from it at any given time?

Comment: Here's the steps to follow to create a VM Image in Azure. First you need to deallocate it, then use Azure CLI interface to make your image. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-custom-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you do makes the file disappear, but on my side, it works well. Sysprep just removes all your personal account and security information and then prepares the machine to be used as an image. You can see the feathers of it from [Sysprep overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview).

To create a custom VM image, see [Create a managed image of a generalized VM in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource). I suggest that creating an image directly from the VM ensures that the image includes all of the disks associated with the VM, including the OS disk and any data disks.

For the creation of multiple identical instances, you can use the [Azure VM Scale Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview). The VMs are identical, load balanced in a group, so if you want to specialize one of them, you need to specialize all of them through a custom image.

Also, you can use the [Azure Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple) to create multiple individual VMs, they are 他the independent VMs, you can specialize any one of them, not all of them, but uniform management is a little difficult.

You can get more details about the difference between them, see [Differences between virtual machines and scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview#differences-between-virtual-machines-and-scale-sets).